# React not rerendering the component when prop changes

Tags: reactjs

I have a picklist component that render some children based on the selected option. The problem comes when I render the same component in two options but with different props, because in that case, the component is not rerendered with the new props.

Let me clarify the problem: I have a picklist, I select option "A", then a text component is rendered below the picklist, I type "error" in that text field, then select option "B" in the picklist, then the other text field component disappear and another text field component is rendered just below the picklist. The last component should have been rendered empty, but the problem is that it contains the word "error".

Here's a minimized version of the code reproducing the error:

```js
import React from "react";

class TextField extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: props.value };
  }

  _onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.currentTarget.value });
  };

  _handleBlur = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.currentTarget.value.trim() });
  };

  render() {
    const { value } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <label>TextField</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          onChange={this._onChange}
          onBlur={this._handleBlur}
          value={value}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Picklist extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { selectedOption: "" };
    this.options = ["Blank", "A", "B"];
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line consistent-return
  _handleSelectorCallback = (newOption) => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption: newOption.currentTarget.value });
  };

  _renderChildren(selectedOption) {
    if (!selectedOption) {
      return null;
    }
    if (selectedOption === "A") {
      return <TextField value="optionA"/>;
    }
    if (selectedOption === "B") {
      return <TextField value="optionB"/>;
    }
  }

  _renderOptions() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return this.options.map((option) => (
      <option value={option} selected={selectedOption === option}>
        {option}
      </option>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div>
          <label>Demo of the Error!</label>
          <select
            onChange={this._handleSelectorCallback}
            value={selectedOption}
          >
            {this._renderOptions()}
          </select>
        </div>
        {this._renderChildren(selectedOption)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Picklist;
```

Ignore how bad the component is written, is just to reproduce the error I'm having. Any idea why the component is not being rerendered with a new value?

Comment: I am kinda confused, you didn't use `props` in the `PickList` component. Would it be possible to provide a codesandbox environment with that minimal code?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-gagarin-6h5u6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I have made a little edit to the code in order to clarify the code.

Comment: When I replace `{this._renderChildren(selectedOption)}` with `{selectedOption === "A" && <TextField value="optionA" />}` 
       ` {selectedOption === "B" && <TextField value="optionB" />}` it works as intended. Investigating why that happens...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what's happening is, when you switch from one `<TextField>` to the other, React is trying to be efficient by just passing different props to the same instance. You can tell React they are different and should be rerendered by adding a key:

```
_renderChildren(selectedOption) {
    if (!selectedOption) {
      return null;
    }
    if (selectedOption === "A") {
      return <TextField key="A" value="optionA" />;
    }
    if (selectedOption === "B") {
      return <TextField key="B" value="optionB" />;
    }
  }
```

alternatively, you could make your `TextField` a controlled component, which means it has no internal state, and the value/onChange fn are passed in as props. I edited your codesandbox to follow this pattern: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-wind-43jq4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is great. One question if you happen to know: I tried to implement `shouldComponentUpdate` with `return this.props.value !== nextProps.value` and it still didn't update. Why might be the reason for that?

Comment: Because the state is assigned in the constructor, even if the component did update it wouldn't rerun the constructor

Answer (score 1):

I tried your sandbox.  Your `TextField` component does not get unmounted so it's constructor gets called just once.  Every change you make that has to do with that component, goes to it's `componentDidUpdate` hook.

So this is what you are missing:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
   if (this.state.value !== this.props.value) {
     this.setState({ value: this.props.value });
   }
}
```